jcodec error: reads package org.jcodec.scale from both jcodec and jcodec.javase
I am building a JavaFX app that uses modules in a Maven project via IntelliJ IDE. I am trying to use jcodec to convert a series of screenshots into a movie. I use the JCodec example Making a video with a set of images from memory. As I am using buffered images, I have included the following dependencies.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jcodec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcodec</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jcodec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcodec-javase</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.5</version>
</dependency>

My module-info file contains the following:
requires jcodec.javase;
requires jcodec;

With this inclusion, I get the following error.
module com.ozank.mymodule reads package org.jcodec.scale from both jcodec and jcodec.javase
What am I missing?
I looked at various posts here to solve the dependency issues but needed help finding an exact match for this problem, especially for jcodec.
There are some pointers to excluding dependencies, but before spending hours, asking for a more direct solution might be a good idea.

I may be overlooking something, but [tag:jcodec] does not appear to be a Java module. Although it's a dependency of your program, your module-info should not require it.

If I don't add the require statement, I get the usual error.

Does your application need to be modular at all? Can you just remove your "module-info.java" file?

yes, it needs to be modular.

As discussed here, in a modular project, "the dependencies must all themselves be modules." You may be able to convert [tag:jcodec]; more here.

See also What is an automatic module?

See also How to create a module-info class file and add it to the jar?

I was hoping for a less hacky solution. Please do not hesitate to update this if anything comes up.

I'll try to summarize my research later today.

The error arises because your modular project has a depenendency on JCodec in your pom.xml and it requires jcodec in your module-info. As discussed here, "the dependencies must all themselves be modules." JCodec is not presently modular, and the issue has arisen before.
Non-modular project: If your project does not need to be modular, delete module-info.java and rely on your existing maven dependencies; use the maven-dependency-plugin to collect the dependencies. You can exclude JavaFX, which can run on the module path. A complete example is available here:
<excludeGroupIds>org.openjfx</excludeGroupIds>

See also What is an automatic module?
Modular project: If your project must be modular, then its dependencies must be modular and have a module-info.java. Some advantages are outlined here. In the particular case of JCodec, pull request #363 may guide the conversion process.
See also How to create a module-info class file and add it to the jar?

Your problem is that you have a split package in your dependent libraries.  Code from one package (org.jcodec.scale) exists in two modules (jcodec and jcodec.javase), which is prohibited by the Java Platform Module System.
Some ways to work around this:

Get the library developers to update the library to not split packages across multiple jars.


The library developers should fix it, but they haven't as of now so it is now your problem.


You could place those jars on the classpath rather than the module path.


Gradle does that by default, Maven does not.
You could switch to Gradle or, if you stick with Maven, there may be a way to configure Maven to not place jar files on the module path if they are not fully modular (fully modular jars have a module-info.class file).


You could rebuild the jar files yourself.


To do this, make your project multi-modular, define a maven module in your project that has dependencies on the jars with split packages, use the maven shade plugin to extract the classes from the jars, and assemble the classes with the assembly plugin into a single artifact (jar file) which you publish to your local maven repository and use that artifact as the dependency in your project rather than the multiple jars with split packages.
You could do this as one-time thing (which is simpler) using the jar and mvn tools from the command line if you prefer rather than doing it as part of a maven project via maven plugins.  Unjar the jars with split files the same directory, then jar them up again into a single jar file and publish that to your local maven repository with the mvn tool.
This is further described in: JDK9 Automatic Modules and "Split Packages" Dependencies
If switching to Gradle, I think the badass jlink plugin does something like this for you automatically.


Make your project non-modular.


To do this don't define a module-info.java for your project.
You can add JavaFX modules via command line switches or use a JDK such as Azul JDK FX that includes JavaFX.

